# Access Browser Control jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ms-access, vba

I have a form with a web browser control. I have a function which sets the value of a dropdown and then calls the jQuery change function:

```
Private Sub setDropDown(elemID As String, elemValue As Variant)

Dim elem As HTMLSelectElement
Dim i As Integer, win As Object

Set elem = Me.webBrowser.Object.Document.getElementById(elemID)
elem.Value = elemValue
Set win = Me.webBrowser.Object.Document.parentWindow
win.execScript "$('#" & elemID & "').change();"

End Sub
```

I call this for two different dropdowns in the `webBrowser_DocumentComplete` event:

```
setDropDown "locationType", "1-4XB-2400"
setDropDown "areaType", "1-4XB-1958"
```

When this event fires these calls do not work. Yet, I also added a command button and added the exact same commands to the click event and this works without fail. I have tried changing the focus in DocumentComplete event and adding pauses of various length. None of this seems to work.

If it helps the selects are of the class dynamicOptionList from the [JavaScript toolbox](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com) and I do not have control of the page. Also, it does not appear that I can call the `change()` event but via jQuery.

Comment: If it works from a command button but not from the event then that points to a timing problem: DocumentComplete may fire before the dynamic content is fully built.  However, you note that adding a pause didn't solve the issue - where did you add it, and for how long?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I put in a 15 second pause immediately before executing the above commands.

Comment: Put a loop in that does a `Sleep`, `DoEvents` and test for existence of `webBrowser.Object.Document.getElementById(elemID)`

Comment: Thanks dbmitch. Not the problem though. I have no trouble getting the handle of the element. It is setting the value that is the issue.

Comment: OK. Figured this one out. The problem was that there was a script that set select values after the page was loaded. So I would set in the documentcomplete event and then it would be overridden subsequent. Pause does not fix this.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Figured this one out. The problem was that there was a script that set select values after the page was loaded. So I would set in the documentcomplete event and then it would be overridden subsequent. Pause does not fix this.

Workaround was to add onchange event to the javascript object:

```
Public Sub setDropDown(elem As String, val As String)
    Dim sel As IHTMLSelectElement
    Dim head As IHTMLElement
    Dim script As IHTMLScriptElement
    Dim setVar As String, elemVar As String

    Set head = wb.Object.Document.getElementsByTagName("head")(0)
    Set script = wb.Object.Document.createElement("script")
    setVar = "_" & elem & "Set"
    elemVar = "_" & elem
    script.Text = "var " & elemVar & "= document.getElementById('" & elem & "'); " + _
        "var " & setVar & "=0; " + _
        "if (" & elemVar & "!= undefined) { " + _
            elemVar & ".setAttribute('onchange', function() { " + _
                "if (" & setVar & "==0) { " + _
                    elemVar & ".value = '" & val & "'; " + _
                    setVar & "= 1;" + _
                "}" + _
            "});" + _
        "};"
    head.appendChild script

End Sub
```